# Question about Divergence of Disturbance Flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, operators, flow

If we break down a flow past a particle into both the incident and disturbance flow like:$$\mathbf{u}^\infty+\mathbf{u}^D=\mathbf{u}^{total}   $$

Can we show that:
 $$ \nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}=0 \Rightarrow \nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}^D=0 $$

Any guidance would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf{u}^\infty$ is the flow in the absence of the particle. It is obtained by solving Navier-Stokes equation (or Stokes flow equation, if you are working in that regime) and continuity equation $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}^\infty=0$, when the particle is not present. So $\mathbf{u}^\infty$ is solenoidal to begin with, and since we require total velocity to be solenoidal, it follows that disturbance velocity must be solenoidal. Symbolically:
$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}^{total}=0~\textrm{and}~\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}^\infty=0\Rightarrow \nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}^D=0$$